# How do I make a multi-output Tensorflow 2 custom training loop for both regression and classification?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I made a minimally reproducible example with the Iris dataset. I made an entire neural network that predicts the last column of the Iris features. I also want to output the target (category). So, the network must minimize two different loss functions (continuous, and categorical). All is set for the continuous target in the next example. But, how do I turn it into a multi-output problem?

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
tf.keras.backend.set_floatx('float64')
iris, target = load_iris(return_X_y=True)

X = iris[:, :3]
y = iris[:, 3]
z = target

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X, y, z)).batch(8)

class MyModel(Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        self.d0 = Dense(16, activation='relu')
        self.d1 = Dense(32, activation='relu')
        self.d2 = Dense(1)

    def call(self, x):
        x = self.d0(x)
        x = self.d1(x)
        x = self.d2(x)
        return x

model = MyModel()

loss_object = tf.keras.losses.MeanAbsoluteError()
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-4)

loss = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name='categorical loss')
error = tf.keras.metrics.MeanAbsoluteError()

@tf.function
def train_step(inputs, target):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        output = model(inputs)
        run_loss = loss_object(target, output)

    gradients = tape.gradient(run_loss, model.trainable_variables)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))

    loss(run_loss)
    error(target, output)


for epoch in range(50):
    for xx, yy, zz in ds: # what to do with zz, the categorical target?
        train_step(xx, yy)

    template = 'Epoch {:>2}, MAE: {:>5.2f}'
    print(template.format(epoch+1,
                        loss.result()))

    loss.reset_states()
    error.reset_states()
```

Answer (score 6):

You can pass a list of losses to `tape.gradient`, like so:

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        pred_reg, pred_cat = model(inputs)
        reg_loss = loss_obj_reg(y_reg, pred_reg)
        cat_loss = loss_obj_cat(y_cat, pred_cat)

    gradients = tape.gradient([reg_loss, cat_loss], model.trainable_variables)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))
```

Full example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
iris, target = load_iris(return_X_y=True)

X = tf.cast(iris[:, :3], tf.float32)
y = tf.cast(iris[:, 3], tf.float32)
z = target

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X, y, z)).shuffle(150).batch(8)

class MyModel(Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        self.d0 = Dense(16, activation='relu')
        self.d1 = Dense(32, activation='relu')
        self.d2 = Dense(1)
        self.d3 = Dense(3, activation='softmax')

    def call(self, x, training=None, **kwargs):
        x = self.d0(x)
        x = self.d1(x)
        a = self.d2(x)
        b = self.d3(x)
        return a, b

model = MyModel()

loss_obj_reg = tf.keras.losses.MeanAbsoluteError()
loss_obj_cat = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy()

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-4)

loss_reg = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name='regression loss')
loss_cat = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name='categorical loss')

error_reg = tf.keras.metrics.MeanAbsoluteError()
error_cat = tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()

@tf.function
def train_step(inputs, y_reg, y_cat):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        pred_reg, pred_cat = model(inputs)
        reg_loss = loss_obj_reg(y_reg, pred_reg)
        cat_loss = loss_obj_cat(y_cat, pred_cat)

    gradients = tape.gradient([reg_loss, cat_loss], model.trainable_variables)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))
    loss_reg(reg_loss)
    loss_cat(cat_loss)

    error_reg(y_reg, pred_reg)
    error_cat(y_cat, pred_cat)

template = 'Epoch {:>3}, SCCE: {:>5.2f},' \
               ' MAE: {:>4.2f}, SAcc: {:>5.1%}'

for epoch in range(150):
    for xx, yy, zz in ds:
        train_step(xx, yy, zz)

    if (epoch + 1) % 10 == 0:

        print(template.format(epoch+1,
                            loss_cat.result(),
                            error_reg.result(),
                            error_cat.result()))

    loss_reg.reset_states()
    loss_cat.reset_states()

    error_reg.reset_states()
    error_cat.reset_states()
```

```
Epoch  10, SCCE:  1.41, MAE: 0.36, SAcc: 33.3%
Epoch  20, SCCE:  1.14, MAE: 0.31, SAcc: 44.0%
Epoch  30, SCCE:  1.05, MAE: 0.26, SAcc: 41.3%
Epoch  40, SCCE:  0.99, MAE: 0.21, SAcc: 40.0%
Epoch  50, SCCE:  0.94, MAE: 0.19, SAcc: 40.0%
Epoch  60, SCCE:  0.88, MAE: 0.18, SAcc: 40.0%
Epoch  70, SCCE:  0.83, MAE: 0.17, SAcc: 44.7%
Epoch  80, SCCE:  0.77, MAE: 0.17, SAcc: 75.3%
Epoch  90, SCCE:  0.70, MAE: 0.17, SAcc: 76.7%
Epoch 100, SCCE:  0.64, MAE: 0.17, SAcc: 82.7%
Epoch 110, SCCE:  0.58, MAE: 0.16, SAcc: 82.7%
Epoch 120, SCCE:  0.54, MAE: 0.16, SAcc: 88.0%
Epoch 130, SCCE:  0.50, MAE: 0.16, SAcc: 88.7%
Epoch 140, SCCE:  0.47, MAE: 0.16, SAcc: 90.7%
Epoch 150, SCCE:  0.45, MAE: 0.16, SAcc: 90.0%
```

With this ouput you can see both losses are being minimized.

Comment: So, in such a setup, we can't use the `CategoricalCrossentropy()` loss function, because the output would be one-hot. Instead, we have to use the `SparseCategoricalCrossentropy()` loss function so that there wouldn't be any conflict with the regression part. Is that right?

Comment: @M.Innat not really, it's because the 3-category targets are not one-hot encoded.

Comment: Yes, understood. -)

Answer (score 4):

You can do the following. I hope you just need a multi-output network. Here I'm creating a model that looks like follows. But even if you need two separate models, you should be able to easily port this.

```
              x
              | Dense(16)
              x
              | Dense(32)
              x
  Dense(1)   / \ Dense(4, softmax)
            /   \
  (cont)  y_1   y_2  (categorical)
```

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
tf.keras.backend.set_floatx('float64')
import numpy as np

iris, target = load_iris(return_X_y=True)

K.clear_session()
X = iris[:, :3]
y = iris[:, 3]
z = target
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X, y, z)).shuffle(buffer_size=150).batch(32)

class MyModel(Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        self.d0 = Dense(16, activation='relu')
        self.d1 = Dense(32, activation='relu')
        self.d2_1 = Dense(1)
        self.d2_2 = Dense(4, activation='softmax')

    def call(self, x):
        x = self.d0(x)
        x = self.d1(x)
        y_1 = self.d2_1(x)
        y_2 = self.d2_2(x)
        return y_1, y_2

model = MyModel()

loss_objects = [tf.keras.losses.MeanAbsoluteError(), tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy()]
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3)

acc = tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy(name='categorical loss')
loss = tf.keras.metrics.MeanAbsoluteError()
#error = tf.keras.metrics.MeanAbsoluteError()

@tf.function
def train_step(inputs, targets):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        outputs = model(inputs)
        losses = [l(t, o) for l,o,t in zip(loss_objects, outputs, targets)]

    gradients = tape.gradient(losses, model.trainable_variables)
    #print(gradients)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))
    #optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients[1], model.trainable_variables))
    return outputs


for epoch in range(50):
    for xx, yy, zz in ds: # what to do with zz, the categorical target?

        outs = train_step(xx, [yy,zz])

        res1 = acc.update_state(zz, np.argmax(outs[1], axis=1))
        res2 = loss.update_state(yy, outs[0])

    template = 'Epoch {:>2}, Accuracy: {:>5.2f}, MAE: {:>5.2f}'
    print(template.format(epoch+1, acc.result(), loss.result()))

    acc.reset_states()
    loss.reset_states()
```

Comment: I think it can be done more easily. With the simpler line `gradients = tape.gradient([reg_loss, cat_loss], model.trainable_variables)` I get a few percent lower loss and higher accuracy. Can't say why, however. Look [here](https://github.com/nicolas-gervais/tensorflow-dump/blob/master/multi-output-iris).

Answer (score 2):

To solve the multi-task learning problem, the following modules are imported.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
tf.keras.backend.set_floatx('float64')
import numpy as np
```

Then, we define a multi-output network as shown below:

```
                      x
                      | Dense(16)
                      x
                      | Dense(32)
                      x
          Dense(1)   / \ Dense(4, softmax)
                    /   \
 (continuous)  y_cont   y_cat  (categorical)
```

The code is shown below:

```
class MyModel(Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        self.d0 = Dense(16, activation='relu')
        self.d1 = Dense(32, activation='relu')
        self.cont = Dense(1) # Continuous output
        self.cat = Dense(4, activation='softmax') # Categorical output

    def call(self, x):
        x = self.d0(x)
        x = self.d1(x)
        print(x.shape)
        y_cont = self.cont(x)
        y_cat = self.cat(x)
        return y_cont, y_cat

model = MyModel()
```

Next, we define the loss function and an optimizer. We use joint training. The loss function is the sum of mean absolute error for the continuous variable and cross entropy for the category variable.

```
cont_loss_func = tf.keras.losses.MeanAbsoluteError()
cat_loss_func = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy()

def cont_cat_loss_func(real_cont, pred_cont, real_cat, pred_cat):
    return cat_loss_func(real_cat, pred_cat) + cont_loss_func(real_cont, pred_cont)

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-4)
```

The train step is defined as follows:

```
@tf.function
def train_step(inputs, target_cont, target_cat):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        #Forward pass
        output_cont, output_cat = model(inputs)
        #Compute the losses
        total_loss = cont_cat_loss_func(target_cont, output_cont, target_cat, output_cat)

    #Backpropagation
    gradients = tape.gradient(total_loss, model.trainable_variables)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))
    return output_cont, output_cat
```

We train the network for 50 epochs and the performance of the model for each epoch will be shown during training.

```
#Model performance
acc_res = tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy()
mae_res = tf.keras.metrics.MeanAbsoluteError()

for epoch in range(50):
    for xx, yy, zz in ds:
        out_cont, out_cat = train_step(xx, yy, zz)
        res1 = acc_res.update_state(zz, np.argmax(out_cat, axis=1))
        res2 = mae_res.update_state(yy, out_cont)

    template = 'Epoch {:>2}, Accuracy: {:>5.2f}, MAE: {:>5.2f}'
    print(template.format(epoch+1, acc_res.result(), mae_res.result()))

    acc_res.reset_states()
    mae_res.reset_states()
```

---

Instead of using joint training (i.e. summing up the loss of the continuous variable and categorical variable), @thushv89 uses a different method to calculate the loss of the network. But I don't quite understand how it works.

```
loss_objects = [tf.keras.losses.MeanAbsoluteError(), tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy()]
```

```
losses = [l(t, o) for l,o,t in zip(loss_objects, outputs, targets)]
```