# Making Class Activation Map (CAM) for EfficientNetB3 architecture

Tags: tensorflow, efficientnet

I would like to draw a class activation map for a model built upon EfficeintNet B3. But when I follow different tutorials and codes from different sources, it simply fails....

```
#load images
img = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(
        base, target_size=(img_height, img_width))
img_array = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img)
img_array = tf.expand_dims(img_array, 0) # Create a batch
predictions = model.predict(img_array)
score = tf.nn.softmax(predictions[0])


last_conv = model.layers[2].layers[-3]

grad_model = tf.keras.models.Model(
    [model.inputs], [last_conv.output, model.output])
```

Can't build a grad_model

> ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor
> KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 300, 300, 3),
> dtype=tf.float32, name='input_1'), name='input_1',
> description="created by layer 'input_1'") at layer "stem_conv". The
> following previous layers were accessed without issue: []

This is the model:

```
 Model: "sequential_1"
    _________________________________________________________________
    Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
    =================================================================
    sequential (Sequential)      (None, 300, 300, 3)       0         
    _________________________________________________________________
    rescaling (Rescaling)        (None, 300, 300, 3)       0         
    _________________________________________________________________
    efficientnet-b3 (Functional) (None, 10, 10, 1536)      10783528  
    _________________________________________________________________
    global_average_pooling2d (Gl (None, 1536)              0         
    _________________________________________________________________
    dropout (Dropout)            (None, 1536)              0         
    _________________________________________________________________
    dense (Dense)                (None, 128)               196736    
    _________________________________________________________________
    dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 5)                 645       
    =================================================================
```

Comment: Is there any one help?

Comment: try this https://keras.io/examples/vision/grad_cam/

Comment: I tried but failed....cannot do this --> grad_model = tf.keras.models.Model(
        [model.inputs], [model.get_layer(last_conv_layer_name).output, model.output]
    )              Error saying:  f'Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor {x} '

Comment: I think here is the issue of yours `last_conv = model.layers[2].layers[-3]` - look into it.

Comment: You are right. But I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: Anyone can help?

with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
  last_conv_layer = model.layers[2].get_layer('top_activation')
  iterate = tf.keras.models.Model([model.inputs], [model.output, last_conv_layer.output])
  ....... I think the problem lies at "last_conv_layer", so there is error to generate iterate. When I remove last_conv_layers.output, iterate can be generated successfully

Comment: Are you looking for CAN or Grad-CAM?

Comment: I am looking for any method that can display heatmap on the photo.....

Comment: For these heatmap to work, it seems that the final output layer must be directly next to the last convolutional layer? So my model as shown above does not work?

Answer (score 1):

To address the graph disconnected value error, you need to build the grad cam model properly. Here is one of the ways to build a model for grad-cam.

```
import tensorflow as tf 
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(300, 300, 3))

x = keras.applications.EfficientNetB3(
    input_tensor=inputs, # pass input to input_tensor 
    include_top=False,
    weights=None
)

# flat the base model with x.output 
x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x.output) 

# others 
x = layers.Dense(128)(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = layers.Dense(5)(x)

model = keras.Model(inputs, x)

for i, layer in enumerate(model.layers[-10:]):
    print(i, layer.name, layer.output_shape, layer.trainable)
```

```
0 block7b_project_bn (None, 10, 10, 384) True
1 block7b_drop (None, 10, 10, 384) True
2 block7b_add (None, 10, 10, 384) True
3 top_conv (None, 10, 10, 1536) True
4 top_bn (None, 10, 10, 1536) True
5 top_activation (None, 10, 10, 1536) True  # < - We will pick this 2D maps
6 global_average_pooling2d_2 (None, 1536) True
7 dense_2 (None, 128) True
8 dropout (None, 128) True
9 dense_3 (None, 5) True
```

**Build Grad-CAM Model**

```
grad_model = keras.models.Model(
    [model.inputs], 
    [
        model.get_layer('top_activation').output, 
        model.output
     ]
)
```

**Check**

With your setup, you would get a disconnected error with the following code. But now, it wouldn't happen.

```
import numpy as np 

image = np.random.rand(1, 300, 300, 3).astype(np.float32) 

with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    convOutputs, predictions = grad_model(tf.cast(image, tf.float32))
    loss = predictions[:, tf.argmax(predictions[0])]

grads = tape.gradient(loss, convOutputs)
print(grads.shape) 
(1, 10, 10, 1536) # NO DISCONNECTED ERROR
```

To get the heatmaps from your grad-cam model, check the following answers and sources as references.

- [Grad-CAM](https://keras.io/examples/vision/grad_cam/)
- [Guided-GradCAM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66189774/9215780)
- [Grad-CAM mult-output Model](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65252186/9215780)
- [GradCAM-Callback](https://www.kaggle.com/ipythonx/keras-ranzcr-multi-attention-efficientnet-tpu?scriptVersionId=88108908&cellId=36)
- [Swin-Transformer : GradCAM](https://www.kaggle.com/ipythonx/tf-hybrid-efficientnet-swin-transformer-gradcam)

Comment: You should be able to solve your issue. Let me know.

Comment: When I reload the model, model = tf.keras.models.load_model(data_dir), the efficientNet CNN is wrapped within layer2 of the model.
grad_model = tf.keras.models.Model(
        [model.inputs], [model.layers[2].get_layer('top_activation').output, model.output])

I still get a graph disconnection error.

Comment: There is a data augmentation layer before CNN, not sure if this is the problem...

Comment: The model and weight is here: 
 https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1i95pwnZMABxlpuVI3i9rx73GDBDbooWp?usp=sharing

Comment: And some of the test photos are here:  https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/17T87pRvZPJcvS5f2BVbvscVNJmskmcMv?usp=sharing

Comment: ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 300, 300, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_1'), name='input_1', description="created by layer 'input_1'") at layer "stem_conv". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []

Comment: The graph disconnection seems to occur at the very first convolutional layer of EfficientNet

Comment: In any case, could you please help generate the heatmap overlay on the photos with the model, which are in the google drive shown above, and send it back to me? Thanks a lot......My email is maximus3219@gmail.com