# How to get GRAD-CAM visualization maps for multi-input models? ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor KerasTensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, heatmap, multiple-input

I am training a transfer learning model (DenseNet121) with two inputs (imaging data) and want to plot GRAD-CAM to visualize the activation maps. I am using 3D mages (shape: `128 x 128 x 36`) and as the transfer learning models are 2D, I took the stacks of 3-slices to train the model which I later concatenated, so the prediction image has the shape:(`2,12, 224, 224, 3`)

My code is as follows:

```py
base_model = load_model(model_dir) #pre-trained model is in model_dir
base_model.trainable = False

input1 = Input(shape=(image_size, image_size, 3), name='inp1')
x = data_augmentation(input1)
x = base_model(x, training=False)
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x1 = Dropout(0.5)(x)

input2 = Input(shape=(image_size, image_size, 3), name='inp2')
x = data_augmentation(input2)
x = base_model(x, training=False)
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x2 = Dropout(0.5)(x)

concatenated = layers.concatenate([x1, x2], axis=-1)
output = layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(concatenated)
model = Model([input1, input2], output)
```

I tried to plot GRAD-CAM by following this example in Keras: https://keras.io/examples/vision/grad_cam/

While doing this for the multi-input network, I am getting an error:

```py
ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_2'), name='input_2', description="created by layer 'input_2'") at layer "zero_padding2d_2". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []
```

I believe the error is from this part of the code:

```py
grad_model = keras.models.Model(
        model.inputs, [model.get_layer(last_conv_layer_name).output, model.output]
    )
```

I also tried changing the above to the following, but still getting the same error:

```py
grad_model = tf.keras.models.Model(
        [model.get_layer('inp1').input, model.get_layer('inp2').input], [model.get_layer('densenet121').get_layer('conv5_block16_2_conv').output, model.output])
```

How can I change the above in the case of multi-input models in transfer learning?

Comment: you need to provide more details, like your model code, how you're compiling it, etc

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get class activation map for multi output model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65245923/how-to-get-class-activation-map-for-multi-output-model)

Comment: @Innat, it does not answer the question. I added more code and details in my question.

Comment: As said, please add details in your questions. What is your input like, 2D or 3D? Can't you not run the keras-io/grad-cam example?

Comment: My input is 3D (this information is already included in the question). The error mentioned is what I get when I follow the keras-io/grad-cam example.

Comment: But your input spec is 2D, not 3D `Input(shape=(image_size, image_size, 3)`

Comment: My input images have the shape (128 x 128 x 36) where I have 36 slices of CT images of shape (128, 128). Because the pre-trained models are 2D I re-structured and sliced to take 3 slices at a time so that the input image is (128,128, 3), so I have 12 of those chunks for one (3D) image. I resized those later to (224, 224,3), so that it's compatible with the pre-trained model. I am using multi-phase images and that's why it's dual input. I use batch_size=12 to consider one whole 3D image (consisting of 12 chunks) at a time when training. Now the prediction image has the shape (2,12,224,224,3).

Comment: If possible, please provide reproducible code (colab gist) with some dummy CT data.